mask/roto the part of the texture inside the shader editor
I draw a mask in the image editor. How can I use this custom mask inside the shader editor ? I want to mask out some part of the image texture using mask/roto directly - without have to render the mask first as image using blender compositor or other image editing app.
Is it possible ? I can't find mask node in the shader editor.
EDIT :
I added this new screenshot below.


How do you draw a mask in the Image Editor? Drawing black and white areas on an image? Then you need an Image Texture node in the Shader Editor to use it. And if you don't want it to get lost you should save the image on your drive.

Sorry forgot to mention , I didn't paint a raster image (using paint tool), I draw a vector mask as spline (in image editor , I switched the mode to 'mask' ).

I've just added the screenshot on my post. The option I have now is to load the mask/spline into compositor using 'mask' node , write it out as image file then bring it back into image editor . It takes too many steps.
